# Can't open localhost in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

Recently I can't open any of my vue apps. I tried installing all dependencies with `npm install` and when I run `npm run serve`, I get following errors:

```
    > vue-first-app@0.1.0 serve D:\Software Development\Front-end\1-Vue\14.Animations&Transitions\routingeg
> vue-cli-service serve

'Transitions\routingeg\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Software Development\Front-end\1-Vue\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue-first-app@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the vue-first-app@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\basirpayenda\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-26T12_03_43_305Z-debug.log
```

This error isn't really helpful for me to understand what is wrong, I tried reinstalling vue and vue cli, but still I am getting this error in all my vue apps? Can anyone help? Thank You In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the `&` in the directory name `14.Animations&Transitions` is problematic.